# Circumflex over Numeral with fontspec

Tags: luatex, fontspec, extended-characters

For a music analysis paper I'm working on, I need to enter an arabic numeral with a circumflex over it to represent a musical scale degree. Normally, I can just use `\^3`, but as soon as I load the `fontspec` package, even if I don't change the default font, the circumflex collides with the glyph for the number. (I am using LuaLaTeX.) Here is a minimal example that illustrates the problem:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\begin{document}
\^5 causes a collision!
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: It seems like LuaLaTeX+fontspec cannot handle `\^` well. On the other hand XeLaTeX+fontspec produce good result with Times, Helvetica, and Courier. (bad with Times New Roman and Arial). If you try to copy the result string you will find they are all character `5` following a U+0302, a combining character. The problem might be some PDF/Unicode-wise setting.

Comment: If possible, I'd really like to use the Linux Libertine O font, and with XeLaTex this still results in the same collision.

Comment: Could you use math mode, i.e., type `$\hat{5}$`?

Comment: @Mico But then you need to make sure `\hat` and `5` are in your font. If so, then it is not guaranteed that the spacing is as good as before.

Comment: @Symbol1 - I guess we don't use which font, or font family, the OP employs.

Comment: @Mico No I do not. If OP are satisfied with Computer Modern `$\hat5$` then fine there is no problem. If not, then there is a general problem. That is, unlike Â is a character, 5̂ is not. So either TeX or renderer will do the necessary calculation. But why they fail?

Comment: What about $\hat{\text{5}}$ or $\hat{\mathrm{5}}$?.

Comment: A problem in HarfBuzz? Other pieces of software on my machine render well 5̂ (for instance this should be correctly rendered, it has been input as 5 followed by U+0302).

Comment: @egreg -- on the machine i'm using (windows/firefox 35.0.1 -- yes, i know it needs updating, and i'm waiting for the systems guys to do that) the circumflex overprints the 5; not at all intelligible.  equally bad on ie 9.-/8112.16421

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems a bug somewhere. A temporary workaround:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
%\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}

\newcommand{\hdigit}[1]{%
  \accent\string"02C6 #1%
}

\begin{document}

\^5 causes a collision! And 5^^^^0302 too.

But \hdigit{5} doesn't.

\end{document}
```

[image]